# React Native on android P

Tags: android, react-native, android-9.0-pie

Will react be able to work on android P, as some blogs claims that from android P the custom overlays are not supported. I have some apps using react so feeling little worried.

Comment: still android P dnt have proper name so everything is unclear .. will clear soon by android ...

Answer (score 0):

Just try it! The Android P developer preview is now available: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/03/previewing-android-p.html

There is no mention there of custom overlays not being supported, and it is extremely unlikely that Google would drop support for something as widespread as React Native - and even if they did, they would give you *plenty* of warning. The most notable thing in Android P in terms of backwards compatibility problems is removing support for hidden API calls, but even that is being done in a slow manner - note the language they use, which shows they are slowly rolling out changes precisely because they expect some apps to be broken because of them and require changing (from https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/02/improving-stability-by-reducing-usage.html):

> **Starting** in the next release of Android ...
>
> **some** non-SDK methods and fields will be restricted ...
>
> Initially, this restriction will impact interfaces with low or no usage.

(emphasis mine)

If they are going to make a change that would prevent React Native apps from running on a future Android version, they would have signaled it.

Your best approach is to download the developer preview of Android P, and run your apps in the emulator to make sure they still work.